# appending an array in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array, append

I need to create an empty array and append new arrays at certain times in a for loop.
Each new array has 2 dimensions (time (1024 elements), Voltage (1024 elements)).
I am controlling a 3 dimensional motorized system and at each time I move, I need to capture data from oscilloscope.
Below is an outline in pseudo-code:

```
For loop
empty_aray=[]
for i=1:10
    move motor at z direction
    get data from oscilloscope
    append to empty_aray

    for j=1:10
        move motor at y direction
        get data from oscilloscope
        append to empty_aray

        for j=1:10
            move motor at y direction
            get data from oscilloscope
            append to empty_aray
        end 
    end 
end
```

The parts are done I just need to know a proper way how to get append new data to existing data and then play with it or get 3D dimensional map of system.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple.  Assuming that `empty_array` will be a 3D array, use [`cat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html) and concatenate / append in the third dimension.  Assuming that your data is stored in `data` and it is a 2D array, and the data that you want to append is stored in `output`, simply do this in your `for` loop:

```
data = cat(3, data, output);
```